The magnitude of work done by a gas that undergoes a reversible expansion along the path ABC shown in the figure is ______
The magnitude of work done by a gas that undergoes a reversible expansion along the path ABC shown in the figure is ______

I am stuck with the fact that the graph starts at $(2,2)$.
Hence I have come up with 2 of its conclusions:

Take area under given P-V graph assuming $(2,2)$ to be reference point.

$$ \Rightarrow W_{ABC }= W_{AB} + W_{AC} = 36+12= 48 $$

Take area under P-V graph assuming $(0,0)$ to be reference point.

$$  \Rightarrow W_{ABC} = W_{AB} + W_{AC} = 48+20= 68 $$
Which of these is the correct way to solve this problem and why. Kindly explain the complete thought process for choosing one of these and also why the other one is wrong.
(Reference : JEE Main 2020)

The rule "Take area under P-V graph" implicitly assumes the x-axis has the coordinate y=0"

Hint: while the gas has a constant pressure and volume, is any work being done?

@Poutnik do you mean to say that the second method is correct?

@DrMoishePippik When volume is constant, no P-V work is done but I'm afraid I did'nt get the hint

@Poutnik I first came up with the second method but after checking answers, my answer got opinionated and I got confused whether this is some case of shifting of graph (and assuming (2,2) to be origin) or just a standard. I need to know the logic of the first method (since that is the correct answer) as my first instinct will always make me follow the second method until and unless there is a reasonable argument for the first one...

@Poutnik I could have considered that if it was not from the mighty JEE exam :(

No logical reasoning can lead to such a blatant error. There  is only one correct value. Their "correct" answer leads to infinite number of solutions, as you can choose the origin arbitrarily. // An area of a 2D object does not depend on the way how you draw the coordinate system axis. // Give them what they expect and if applicable, add a comment that it is wrong.

The path expected is ABC so starts at (2,2) and ends at (12,2) not (12,0).

@porphyrin That is what I want to know why? otherwise the answer given by Poutnik is what seems reasonable to me

As I read the question the pressure never goes below 2, and the volume is never smaller than 2.

@porphyrin I'm afraid that does not prove anything. Let's say the red coordinate axes of image 2 would be the original question, then would we apply the logic that "the pressure never goes below 2, and the volume is never smaller than 2", or simply find the area under whatever figure it is?

The geometrical area method of integration has to be applied either correctly, either not at all. IEE task authors chose the third option by trivial error. There is not much reasoning about providing error, but by science studying human behavior. // As the authority is often a big deal in India, many students accept a wrong answer presented as valid.

What I mean is that you are only asked to find the work done in the area ABC not the total work done to bring you to the starting point (2,2) and from (12,2) (point C)  to (12,0) so you do not need this extra bit.

Your problem is not related to physical chemistry, but to mathematics. Particularly to integration of mathematical functions. That is a fancy name for determining the 2D area between function curve $y=f(x)$ and the three lines $y=0$, $x=a$, $x=b$.
Attempts to replace $x=0$ by $x \ne 0$ give a wrong result.
An area of a 2D object does not depend on the way how you draw the coordinate system axis.
Work done by the system via expansion:
$$W = \int_A^B{p(V) \cdot \text{d}V}+\int_B^C{p(V) \cdot \text{d}V}\\
=(\pu{8 Pa})(\pu{8 m3} - \pu{2 m3}) + (\frac{\pu{8 Pa} + \pu{2 Pa}}{2})(\pu{12 m3} - \pu{8 m3})\\
=\pu{48 Pa m3}+ \pu{20 Pa m3}=\pu{68 J}$$

:D To be precisely honest, I am very much aware of integration, but since a large portion of the society is inclined towards a different answer than mine (you might want to check this question out on the internet), I want to know their opinion - whether they just accept it, if there is some chemistry, or something I don't know... because I totally agree with your reasoning...

Surprising number of people are willing to accept wrong answers if it is promoted by a high enough authority, without much thinking about it.
